# Dynamic Bootstrap list with collapse is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have created dynamic list using bootstrap and thymeleaf, list also contains collapse functionality which is not working properly, aria-expanded = "false" is not working, I browsed a lot but not any solution for dynamically created list using thymeleaf.

- When the page loads all collapsible panel should be closed for that I used aria-expanded="false", but it is not working.
- As the list comes into from it takes few clicks to achieve collapse.

Below there is the code and image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title></title>
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
        <link href="/resources/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
        <link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/resources/css/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/resources/css/icheck.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/resources/css/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/resources/css/custom-accordin.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" th:fragment="content">
        <header>
            <!--Main Navigation-->
            <nav class="navbar fixed-top scrolling-navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark blue-grey darken-2">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="EmployerDashboard.html"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></a> </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Submission status</a> </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!--Main Navigation-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!--Grid row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="mx-auto">
                        <div class="alert blue-grey lighten-4" role="alert" style="border-top: 2px solid #000;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col text-center">
                                    <p class="h6"><strong th:text="${efiledHdrBean.payPeriod}"></strong><br/>
                                        <small>Submission Period</small></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-center">
                                    <p  class="h6"><strong th:text="${@codeMapUtil.getCodeValue(efiledHdrBean.payFreq, 'PAY_FREQ_DESC').concat('ly')}"></strong><br/>
                                        <small>Pay Frequency</small></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-center">
                                    <p  class="h6"><strong th:text="${efiledHdrBean.ppType}"></strong><br/>
                                        <small>Pension Prov.</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <p class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i> Your Contribution data is accepted by NEST<br />
                            Amount Due to Pension provider: <strong>&pound; 40.72</strong></p>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group" >

                            <div class="accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

                               <!--  <li class="list-group-item" th:each="listBean,iterator: ${contributionStatus}"> -->
                                     <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="card" th:each="listBean,iterator: ${contributionStatus}" >

                                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" th:id="'heading' + ${iterator.index}"> <a class="collapsed black-text" data-toggle="collapse" th:href="'#collapse' + ${iterator.index}" aria-expanded="false" th:attr = "aria-controls='collapse' + ${iterator.index}"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon float-right"></i>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-7"> <span class="icon-round pull-left">
                                                    <p class="icon"><span th:text=" ${#strings.substring(listBean.eeSurname,0,1) + #strings.substring(listBean.eeFname,0,1)}"></span></p>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <p class="h5 list-group-item-heading"><strong><span th:text="${listBean.eeSurname}"></span> , <span th:text="${listBean.eeFname}"></span></strong></p>
                                                    <p class="list-group-item-text mb-2"><span th:text="${listBean.eeWksNo}"></span> <span class="badge grey lighten-2 black-text" th:text="${listBean.assessStatus}"></span></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-4 pr-0">
                                                    <p class="h5 list-group-item-heading text-right"><span class="float-left">&pound;</span><span th:text="${listBean.eePenEarnings}"></span></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </a> </div>

                                        <div  th:id="'collapse' + ${iterator.index}" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordionEx"  th:attr="aria-labelledby='heading' + ${iterator.index}">
                                            <div class="card-body black-text">
                                                <p class="h6">Pensionable Earnings: &pound; <span th:text="${listBean.eePenEarnings}"></span></p>
                                                <ul class="list-group" >
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-5 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Employer</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-4 p-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Rate(%): <span th:text="${listBean.erContribRate}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-3 pl-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading text-right mb-0"><span class="float-left">&pound;</span><span th:text="${listBean.erDedValue}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-5 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Employee</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-4 p-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Rate(%): <span th:text="${listBean.eeContribRate}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-3 pl-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading text-right mb-0"><span class="float-left">&pound;</span><span th:text="${listBean.eeDedValue}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-9 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Additional Voluntary Contribution (AVC)</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-3 pl-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading text-right mb-0"><span class="float-left">&pound;</span><span th:text="${listBean.eeAvcDedValue}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list-group-item grey lighten-4">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-9 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0"><strong>Total Contribution</strong></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-3 pl-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading text-right mb-0"><strong><span class="float-left">&pound;</span><span th:text="${listBean.erContribution}"></span></strong></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                                <ul class="list-group mt-4" aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <li class="list-group-item grey lighten-3">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-9 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-text mb-0"><strong>Partial / Non-Payment of Contribution</strong></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-5 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Reason</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading text-right mb-0"><span th:text="${listBean.partialContribReason}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-5 pr-0">
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading mb-0">Effective Date</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <p class="list-group-item-heading text-right mb-0"><span th:text="${listBean.partialContribEffectiveDate}"></span></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                              </div>  
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card-->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--Main container-->
        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js}"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/popper.min.js}"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
        <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/mdb.min.js}"></script><!-- 
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/thymol.js}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/thymolconfig.js}"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/js/custom.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/numericfield.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/moment.2.10.6.min.js}"></script>
        <!-- SCRIPTS -->

        <!-- <!-- thymol JavaScript -->

        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/main.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/sweet-alert.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/utils.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/numericfield.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/date.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/icheck.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/dynamicFormFields.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/moment.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery.qtip.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/resources/js/bc-quicklink.js}"></script>
            <script th:inline="javascript">
                /*<![CDATA[*/
        // SideNav Initialization
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
                edge: 'right',
                closeOnClick: true 
                });
                var container = document.getElementById('slide-out');
                Ps.initialize(container);
        });
        </script>
        <script>
        // Material Select Initialization
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.mdb-select').material_select();
        });
        /*]]>*/


        </script>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help me to solve the problem.

[image: Image containing dynamic list with improper display]

Comment: can you create js fiddle?

Comment: I can't create Js fiddle since list is created using dynamic values which comes from server.

Comment: You could create a small js fiddle example using random values (maybe just parts of the created HTML). It is hardly possible to determinate the error while dealing with all that lines of code and the thymeleaf-expressions.